# Square of sum of matrices

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to follow [these lecture notes on Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA)](http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l10.pdf) but I can't seem to figure out how the author gets from:

$$ \Sigma_{x\epsilon\omega_{i}} (w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i})^2$$

to

$$ \Sigma_{x\epsilon\omega_{i}} w^{T}(x-\mu_{i})(x-\mu_{i})^Tw$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, $w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i}$ is a scalar we can write it as:

$w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i} = (w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i})^T$

Thus,

$(w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i})^2 = (w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i}) (w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i})^T$

Now, we know that:

$(AB)^T = B^TA^T$

Thus, we have:

$(w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i}) (w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i})^T = w^{T} (x - \mu_{i}) (w^{T} (x - \mu_{i}))^T$$

Or in other words:

$(w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i}) (w^{T}x - w^{T}\mu_{i})^T = w^{T} (x - \mu_{i}) (x - \mu_{i})^T w$

Comment: Ahh, makes sense now, thanks!